# Does an element of a group to the 0th power equal the identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My textbook doesn't explain this well at all.

I was thinking about how a group follows the axiom that $xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x = 1$, where $x$ is some element of the group, $1$ is the identity and $x^{-1}$ is $x$'s inverse. The book says that the powers of some $x$ work with the binary operation on itself.

For example I think for $(\mathbb{Z} , + )$, $1^5$ would be $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5$. It then goes to say that you can manipulate exponents as usual... which makes me wonder. Since $xx^{-1} = x^{1-1} = 1 = x^0$, does that mean that an element of a group to the power of $0$ will always be the identity of that group?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar If your operation is $+$, and you use exponentiation to denote repeated operations, then, yes, $1^5=5$...

Comment: If you want the law $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$ to hold for every pair $(m,n)$ of *integers*, then you are forced to conclude that $a^{0}=e$ and $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've basically given the proof, but maybe seeing it written this way is clearer.

Take any element $x$ from any group $G$. Since $G$ is a group, you can find $x^{-1} \in G$.

On the one hand, the definition of inversion implies $xx^{-1} = 1$ (the identity of $G$).

On the other hand, the definition of exponentiation implies $xx^{-1} = x^{1 - 1} = x^0$.

Comparing the previous two lines of reasoning, we see $x^0 = 1$, since both are equal to $xx^{-1}$.

Comment: In other words, the assignment of $x^0 = 1$ plays nice with $x^ax^b = x^{ab}$ for all $a$ and $b$, a desirable property.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is certainly morally correct. But it might be clearer to say that initially $x^0$ has no meaning, as per group axioms. We must define it. If we define it as $id$ then the original identity is a tautology. But the point is that this definition plays nicely with the definition of $x^n$, $n>0$, which I guess was in your book.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412683/proofs-request-proofs-that-five-exponention-rules-hold-for-positive-real-bases/4412691#4412691

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to give a sharper "answer" than in other answers and comments. Namely, first, naming/notating $x$-inverse as $x^{-1}$ does *not* actually allow an argument $e=x\cdot x^{-1}=x^{1-1}=x^0$, until we have established our notational conventions about exponents!

The main logical ordering that I know for this is, first, to inductively let $x^n=(x^{n-1})\cdot x$ for $1\le n\in \mathbb Z$. This part is uncontroversial, I think. Then define notation $x^0=e$ and $x^{-n}=$ $x^n$-inverse. Still, there is some checking to be done, that these definitions/notations do satisfy the (expected/desired) "rules of exponents". A few cases, etc.

But, so, then, the convention/definition $x^0=e$ is just a convention that is compatible with other stuff, as several other people noted. It is not innately "mathematically true".