# Is this something new? If $x^n=y^z$, then $x=y^{z/n}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I was just messing around with some exponential equations and stumbled upon this general expression.

> If $x^n=y^z$, then $x=y^{z/n}$.

After further evaluation, I concluded that it is just a general method in which to find the root of two sides of an equation to find an unknown base (in this case $x$).

Comment: i am literally a high school student so i am still unaware of several maybe obvious concepts that may deem this result useless or incorrect for that matter.

Comment: This is not true. For example, $(-1)^2 = 1^{2}$, but $-1 \neq 1^{2/2}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: looks fine :-) this is a nice (re)discovery! but the manupulations you have done do not always hold. can you find conditions under which your manupulations would work?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe what if one were find the absolute values of the bases like so: |-1|^2 = 1^2 and for your counter example |-1|=1^2/2 ?

Comment: @Math-fun your wording of rediscovery implies that something like this already exists yes? If possible could you give me the name of this property so i can read more into it. And yes lol i just found conditions in which the manipulation is indeed invalid

Comment: This is just a generic consequence of rules of exponents (which are taught in elementary algebra).

Comment: let's say $y^z=a$ then $x^n=a$. By definition, $x$ is $n$-th root of $a$

Comment: It's true *if* you assume that all variables are positive real numbers.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but this may explain some things you are learning about exponents. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412683/proofs-request-proofs-that-five-exponention-rules-hold-for-positive-real-bases/4412691#4412691

Comment: Welcome to MSE, and congrats on having fun finding something new to you. As others have pointed out, this is well-known, though it has limits: negative and complex numbers make it go all squirrelly and either untrue or indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is

> If $x^n=y^z$, then $x=y^{z/n}$.

Put some parentheses in the right places and we have

> > If $x^n=y^z$, then $\left(x^n\right)^{1/n}=x=\left(y^z\right)^{1/n}$

which follows from the laws of exponents $$\left(a^m\right)^n=a^{mn}.$$

This simply suggests that $(\cdot)^n$ and $(\cdot)^{1/n}$ are inverse operations when we have $(\cdot)^n$ [well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined_expression).

Answer (score 1):

There are some conditions to consider for this equation...

1. If $n=0$, we would have  $x^0 = y^z \rightarrow 1 = y^z$, which implies $y = z = 1$.  Conversely, If $z=0$, then $x^n = 1$, for which the only solution in real numbers would be $n=0$.
2. If $y \lt 0$ and $n$ is even, the solution does not exist in the real numbers. E.g. if you have $x = -2^{1/2}$, it's equivalent to $x = \sqrt{-2}.$

To sum up, if $x^n = y^z$, then
\begin{cases}
x = y^{z/n}, & \text{$n \neq 0$} \\
x = 1, & \text{if $n=0$ and $y = z = 1$ OR if $n=0$ and $z=0$} \\
x = \text {undefined}, & \text{if $y<0$ and $n$ even}
\end{cases}