# What are the broadest possible restrictions on $a$, and on $b$ and $c$ in the formula ${(a^{b})}^{c}=a^{bc}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, real-numbers

I assumed I could use this identity for any number but I figured it doesn't always work once I tried it with complex numbers.

For example, consider $e^{2aπi}$, with $a  \epsilon  \mathbb{Q}$

According to Euler's formula, $e^{2\pi ai}=\cos{(2\pi a)}+i\sin{(2\pi a)}$, which gives a complex number that depends on the rational number $a$.

However, using the property $
{(a^{b})}^{c}=a^{bc}$, we get:

$e^{2\pi ai}={(e^{2\pi i})}^a=1^a=1$

Comment: In general when you define the function $z \mapsto z^a$ for complex numbers, you have to choose a branch. We define $z^a = \exp(a \ln z)$, and the logarithm is multivalued, which is where the need for a choice of branch comes from.

Comment: There are many questions on this site about that kind of paradox. Does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412683/proofs-request-proofs-that-five-exponention-rules-hold-for-positive-real-bases/4412691#4412691

Comment: Ethan Bolker, I don't have a proof that the property works for all a,b,c in C, so I haven't found a counterexample to something proven for there to be a paradox. What I am asking is up to which level of numbers can we go where there is a clear proof the property holds before the property stops holding beyond that.

Comment: An entirely tangent point on sentence interpretation: the broadest possible *restrictions* would be something like "when $a = b = c = 1$" - at least, if you want the statement to still have some meaning. But everyone knows what you really mean, so feel free to ignore this.